# Schema.org properties for message boards/forums

Tags: schema.org

**Note:** I've successfully come across the correct schema properties for message board posts via [`DiscussionForumPosting`](https://schema.org/DiscussionForumPosting). No need for guidance in that regard.

What would be the most appropriate properties for the **boards** that these posts reside in? I was a little hesitant with using [`Article`](https://schema.org/Article), despite `DiscussionForumPosting`'s deriving from them. To me, an article illustrates a written work, where a board is rather a holding ground for a group of posts.

Any suggestions?